# Is it possible to scroll to hash anchor inside a scrollable div with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm trying to use hash anchors inside a scrollable div (modal) using solely HTML and CSS, but it doesn't seem to be working. Do hash anchor links only work on on the window and not nested scrollable divs? Will I need to use JS for this, or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please post your code with what you've tried? It'll be easier for us to help. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's more just a theoretical question as to whether you can link to hash anchors in a nested scrollable div with HTML, or if that only works on the window.

Comment: Here is a quick and dirty fiddle with it working. https://jsfiddle.net/xzmj82gp/

Comment: Ah okay, I read that name was deprecated in HTML5, and to use id on the nearest div. This is in a React project, does JSX have a 'name' equivalent? edit: nevermind, I see that React Router has a Hash Link module.

Comment: @FRMR I tested it out with `id` and it still worked

Comment: Okay, fair. The issue was definitely that I needed to use the React Router Hash Link package. Thanks for your efforts.